# Passing parameters to Django view through url

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a formset that captures a parameter from the url to prefill one of the fields. The form is displaying correctly and at the correct address, but after clicking "submit" the page redirects to "/correction/" instead of the intended /correction/A07686+dwdID19, and the form does not save. What might be the issue?

In models.py:

```
class correction(models.Model):
    corrected_word = models.ForeignKey(item)
    correction_author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    correction_made = models.IntegerField(u'correction_made', choices=CORRECTION_CHOICES)
    correction_word = models.CharField(u'correction_word', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    approved = models.IntegerField(u'approved', choices=APPROVAL_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.time)
```

In views.py:

```
def submit_corr(request, bdword):
if hasattr(request, 'user') and request.user.is_authenticated():
    word = item.objects.filter(file_position=bdword)[0]
    CorrFormSet = inlineformset_factory(item, correction, fields=['correction_made', 'correction_word','correction_author'], can_delete=False, extra=1)
    form = CorrFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=word, initial=[{'correction_author': request.user,}])


    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            for entry in form:
                entry.save()

    else:
        form = CorrFormSet(instance=word, initial=[{'correction_author': request.user,}])

    return render(request, "correctionform.html", {"form": form,"word": word})
```

In urls:

```
    url(r'^correction/(?P<bdword>.*)$', 'english.views.submit_corr'),
```

In the template:

```
<a href="../correction/{{word.file_position}}">Submit correction</a></th>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check that {{word.file_position}} is actually rendering something. By default it won't if the variable can't be found

Comment: It is passing in the file_position correctly. When clicking on the link, I was able to successfully go to /correction/A07686+dwdID19, with the form displaying correctly and all the prefills filled in. But when I try to submit the form, the form does not save and the page redirects to /correction/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a href="../correction/{{word.file_position}}">Submit correction</a>` doesn't submit a form because it's a link and when you press a link, this sends a request with a GET method to the server so never enter to `if request.method == 'POST':` .

Please try something like

```
<form action="/correction/{{word.file_position}}" method="POST">
{# your inputs fields#}
<button type="submit">Submit correction</button>
</form>
```

I hope to be useful. Regards

Comment: Thanks so much, that helped a lot!